# Trouble accessing VM console OpenStack Juno

Tags: openstack

I have set up a Juno deployment of OpenStack.  I can launch my cirros image:

```
[root@ost-mgmt-el7-001 ~]# nova list
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------+
| ID         | Name     | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks              
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------+
| xxxxxxx | test-007 | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | public-59=10.29.103.13
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------------+
[root@ost-mgmt-el7-001 ~]# ssh 10.29.103.13 -l cirros
cirros@10.29.103.13's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
cirros@10.29.103.13's password: 
$ ls -l
total 0
$ pwd
/home/cirros
$ exit
Connection to 10.29.103.13 closed.
```

But when I attempt to access the console like so ...

```
[root@ost-mgmt-el7-001 ~]# nova get-vnc-console test-007 novnc
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Type  | Url                                                                                         |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| novnc | https://ost-el7.exaple.com:6080/vnc_auto.html?token=xxxxx |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[root@ost-mgmt-el7-001 ~]# curl -v https://ost-el7.exaple.com:6080/vnc_auto.html?token=xxxxx
```

... I get "Empty reply from server" ...

```
* About to connect() to ost-el7.exaple.com port 6080 (#0)
*   Trying 10.29.103.39...
* Connected to ost-el7.exaple.com (10.29.103.39) port 6080 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=ost-el7.exaple.com,O="Example Systems, Inc.",L=San Jose,ST=CA,C=US
*   start date: Feb 18 21:54:13 2015 GMT
*   expire date: Feb 18 21:54:00 2017 GMT
*   common name: ost-el7.exaple.com
*   issuer: CN=HydrantID SSL ICA G2,O=HydrantID (Avalanche Cloud Corporation),C=US
> GET /vnc_auto.html?token=5612703c-06cb-497f-a205-bbebbebb6d9c HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: ost-el7.exaple.com:6080
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host ost-el7.exaple.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Same thing happens if I log on to Horizon and attempt to access the console that way.

I am not sure how to really debug this.  I do not see anything in the /var/log/httpd/*log files that is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to set `ssl_only` to false in my nova.conf.